# Where can I find a decent transparent ajax spinner?

Tags: ajax, spinner

I am trying to find a decent transparent ajax spinner that looks good on any background.  I've gone to ajaxload.info and other various generator sites, but none of them look good on a dark background.  Anyone know where I can get a TRANSPARENT spinner?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because to make them look good you need alpha transparency (that is, partial transparency on a per-pixel basis), the GIF format (the only common animated image format supported in browsers) only supports binary transparency (each pixel is either 100% opaque or transparent).

The only solution I have come up with for GIFs is to generate loaders on the fly based on the background color — even then it won't work with non-solid colors.

The best solution is to either use an animation that doesn't require alpha transparency (Facebook's three blocks is a good example of this) or try out one of the fancy new CSS3/Javascript/Canvas based spinners - because those animate by actually moving (i.e. rotating) a single frame, it can be a PNG with alpha transparency.

Answer (score 20):

I recently switched to PNG sprites that support alpha channel transparency:

[image: example PNG sprite] (generated using http://preloaders.net/ )

Even though they require a tiny javascript loop that changes the offset of the background image, I found them quite useful, especially when submitting (POST) forms to the server (animation of normal GIFs often stops in that case). Also, legacy browsers support it better than rotating or drawing custom elements.

```
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var frames=12; var frameWidth = 15;
        var offset=counter * -frameWidth;
        document.getElementById("spinner").style.backgroundPosition=offset + "px 0px";
        counter++; if (counter>=frames) counter =0;
    }, 100);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ekus/dhRxG/

Comment: This worked very well for me. If it's not clear to others, preloaders.net allows you to download the spinner as a sprite, just select APNG beforehand and "Download as sprites" option after you have generated the image.

Answer (score 9):

Try using http://spiffygif.com

The halo feature described in their [docs](http://spiffygif.com/docs/) provides a workaround solution to this problem

Comment: disappointing, no option of transparent background...

Comment: @SaurabhLP, as Sean mentioned, this is intentional. In their docs Spiffygif argue that halo effect is more aesthetically beautiful than poor GIF transparency http://spiffygif.com/docs/

Comment: @SaurabhLP - Transparent spinners are an option on spiffygif, you just have to select PNG as the file type.  [Here's an example](http://spiffygif.com/?format=png&color=DE00DE,5C00B3,0014C4,0074C7,00ADA1,00BF40,93C900,E8E800,EB9D00,EB4A00,EB007D&lines=11&length=25&radius=15&width=9).  Here's how you animate a sprite: http://codepen.io/sdholbs/pen/GyEDw

Comment: The Halo function solved my problem where I had an image background

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile, since CSS animation support is becoming more and more available, here's an impressive set of 10 CSS-only loading indicators:
http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Answer (score 5):

**Use a font.**

The code will look something like this, using CSS to rotate a single character of a font:

```
<i class="icon-spin3 animate-spin"></i>
```

Check out [Fontello](http://fontello.com) to get an "icon" font. For example, here are some good "spin-able" characters offered in the font "Fontelico":

[image: font spinners]

Using a font also lets you set size, color, and transparency very easily (it's just CSS). And it's rendered as a vector graphic, so you'll always get clean edges regardless of size. Quite nice.

ps - One nice thing about Fontello is that it lets you handpick which characters you want, and then you download a zip file that has the stripped down font files and the css you need. To utilize the animate-spin class, be sure to include/use the animation.css file.

Comment: Does this only work in HTML5 browsers?

Comment: It spins the character using CSS `animation` and `transform`. Support for the `animation` property will be the most limiting factor, requiring IE10 or greater. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation .

Comment: Also, here's the actual CSS for spinning. This is the code that fontello provides when you download their fonts. https://gist.github.com/bseib/7aeef710afe21f8cf2f6

Comment: This is my favorite approach, at least in modern browsers. Works with the free [fontawesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#animated) too.

Comment: Since some of these fonts are open-source, you could in theory modify them so that they contain rotations of the spinner. You could then increment a character somewhere in a DOM to achieve animation.

Comment: @kralyk you only need a single character. You use CSS animation to rotate the single character. That is precisely what the class `animate-spin` is doing. Fontello even gives you the CSS you need.

Comment: @broc.seib AFAIK that's not supported by IE9.

Comment: @kralyk Yep, IE9 doesn't do CSS `animation` or `transform`. See my earlier comment about this limitation.

Comment: @broc.seib Well that was the reason I suggested the multiple character approach, as it works with legacy browsers too :D ... Never mind...